# Client Certification Authentication works but postback causes 403.7 error

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, asp.net-4.0, http-status-code-403, client-certificates

I've been tasked to utilize Client Certification Authentication for communication between an external vendor and our Web Form. I've set-up iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication using oneToOneMappings and the authentication is working fine. SSL Settings is set to 'Require SSL' with client certificates of 'Require', which is a project requirement.

Info:

1. Web Form is using ASP.NET 4.0.
2. IIS 7.5
3. Windows Server 2008 R2

Scenerio:

1. External vendor posts information to us using Client Certification Authentication.
2. Information is interpreted and displayed in the web form.
3. Upon submit, order is created and user will be redirected to the same page but with an additional query string of the created order's id.

Problem:

Upon redirection, a '403.7 - Forbidden: Access is denied' will occur. Could anyone please offer some advice? Is it possible to require client certificate authentication only once, so that any postback or navigation to other pages will not require authentication again?

Answer (score 0):

Found that the error was caused by a redirection to the destination site directly instead of through the proxy network which supplies the client certificate for authentication. Changed the redirection to the proxy instead and the problem is solved.